# How to rearrange entity attributes in Xcode data modeling tool?

Tags: xcode, core-data, interface-builder, data-modeling

May be it is a stupid question, but I think it is quite important to keep entity attributes in  proper order for your eyes. So, how can I move them inside an entity? I tried everything I could with mouse and keyboard.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that is possible. They are always in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They're alphabetized. You can't change the order unless you change the names.